# Run R .ipynb script in terminal

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I wrote some R scripts in ipython notebook followed by [tutorial](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/r-lang/)

Here is one example of R script in .ipynb [image]

In python, we can simply run .ipynb script in the terminal by [runipy](https://pypi.org/project/runipy)

Is any way I could also run R .ipynb scripts **in the terminal** as well?

Eg: `runipy_R R_script.ipynb` in terminal

Comment: Please provide a sample (small, reduced) `.ipynb` script that you're trying to run alone in R.

Comment: [`ipynb script with R`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=ipynb+script+with+R) produced two pages that look promising: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nbconvertR/ and https://rdrr.io/cran/rmarkdown/man/convert_ipynb.html. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @r2evans I added more details above. Thank you so much for the resources. However, I wish to run R_script.ipynb(which I already finished) in the terminal instead of looking for how to convert R to .ipynb.

Comment: I believe both of those functions work *from* a `.ipynb` file and write *to* something else, likely R-markdown being the closest (which you can then run in the RStudio IDE or similar. I don't know if either converts R code to `.ipynb`, not sure where you're getting that. But I don't use Jupyter and don't have a script file handy, so I can't test or demonstrate what those functions advertise doing. Good luck.